# Extension of price and image change

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm looking for an extensions for configurable products. I have a configurable product with several associated simple products, I would like that when the client selects the color and size the extension Gets the image associated with the simple product.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher which does exactly the thing you want.

Comment: so that his works I delete single Product Configurable?

Comment: Well it does "when the client selects the color and size the extension Gets the image associated with the simple product". You can define a simple product which is taken as default or define if the first options is used for retrieving the correct simple product.

Comment: OK thanks it is also the price change?

Comment: By default it does just the image change, but there's a fork of the extension above: https://github.com/nhp/Switcher which also changes the price.

Comment: I have a little problem it displays images and more on the image

Comment: know you another extension?

Comment: I think that's a matter of configuration. Can you give more details what's the issue?

Comment: would it be possible for this contact on skype to check the admin?